# How can I get my facebook tracking pixel to work on my ebay listing?

Tags: facebook-pixel, facebook-pixel-helper

I have created a facebook tracking pixel and have inserted the following code into the html on my ebay listing page:

```
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX3&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
/></noscript>
```

I have verified that the pixel is there via the facebook pixel helper chrome extension. However, when I load the page, the view is not registered on the facebook events manager platform and the chrome extension shows the following error:

> We detected event code but the pixel has not activated for this event,
> so no information was sent to Facebook. This could be due to an error
> in the code, but could also occur if the pixel fires on a dynamic
> event such as a button click.

I have not configured any specific events in the "Web event configurations" section on the facebook platform because the domain is owned by someone else and according to the documentation (https://www.facebook.com/business/help/422408905612648?id=1877298665783613):

> If you can't edit events because another business owns the domain,
> contact the domain owner to share the domain with full control.

Based on the examples I have seen (https://declutter69.com/ebay/how-to-use-the-facebook-pixel-on-ebay-listings/), I didn't think this step was necessary, and I'm not sure how to go about it. I don't know what I'm missing and what has to be done to start seeing these hits on the facebook platform.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You should not ask the same question several times. If your original question has not received an answer, you should modify it instead of asking it again.

Comment: @Oliver Jane this question is about the facebook platform, and the other is about a setup that makes use of an aws lambda. They are not the same question.